# Error on installing pywin32 modul for python 2.7

Tags: python, pywin32

I`m disparately trying to install win32.client which I know is a part of pywin32 module.

I have tried with:

1. pip install
2. pip install and downloaded different versions of .whl files
3. .zip install from cmd (see pics bellow)

My version of python is : [Info of my python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2vB.jpg)

When I tried with pip install:
[I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzsZ7.jpg)

When I tried with pip install and downloaded .whl file: 
[I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGN1l.jpg)

When I tried with .zip file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwENt.jpg)

Do someone has any ideea why is not working ?

- I also uninstalled python and installed again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you uninstall from pip and install with the .exe installer from the [official repository](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases).

This has always worked for me. Remember to select the right version for your version of python.

Answer (score 0):

You may try installing with:

```
conda install -c anaconda pywin32
```

But from the warning;

> You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this.

I would upgrade to python 3 and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately it is mandatory to work on this version of python.